# Shared Element Transition Google Play Nested RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, shared-element-transition

I have a similar structure to that of Google Play.

I have a CoordinatorLayout with vertical RecyclerView having rows of horizontal RecyclerView.

What I want?

I want to transition image from row of horizontal RecyclerView to a new Activity consisting of ViewPager inside CollapsingToolbar.

Comment: There are plenty of resources online regarding shared element transitions. Perhaps you should try to implement it and ask questions if you run into specific problems?

Comment: @Karakuri I have implemented this structure. But I want to understand how I can create transitioning in this complicated structure. I have already implemented this in a simpler case with RecyclerView and DetailActivity. Any help is great for my knowledge. Thanks.

Comment: It's difficult to help if you don't specify exactly what kinds of problems you are having with your implementation.